# Postgres Javascript Promise isn't returning modified result

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql, nodes, javascript-objects

I need some help understanding Javascript promises. I'm using postgres and I want a function that will take an array of objects as per the example below

```
[ { airlineName: 'NZ',
  { airlineName: 'TN']
```

and I want it to return the array as below

```
[ { airlineName: { iatacode: 'NZ', airlineName: 'Air New Zealand' },
{ airlineName: { iatacode: 'TN', airlineName: 'Air Tahiti Nui' }]
```

For simplicity I have simplified the query here, however the query works fine,

The problem arises if I console log the array I get the results in the correct format above, however if I try and return the statement I get undefined passed back!

Any ideas?

```
exports.extractAirlineName = (flightInfo) => {

    db.many("SELECT airline_name FROM airline_info WHERE iatacode IN 'NZ', 'TN'")
   .then(airline => {
    flightInfo.forEach((flight, index) => {
    flight.airlineName = {
        iatacode: flight.airlineName,
        airlineName: airline[index].airline_name
          };

        // this shows the correctly populated object
          console.log(flightInfo);

            //this just returns undefined
          return flightInfo; 
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: ```flightInfo``` will be undefined of async js execution. to be shure that result are handled you need to handle promise upstairs ```extractAirlineName ``` method

Comment: `extractAirlineName` cannot return an array that doesn't exist yet. You could return a promise for it (you're already constructing one!), buy you'd need to `return` it.

Comment: Is it me or the indentation? Looks like you are trying to `return` from a `forEach` callback within a `then` callback.